# In tense can I mix past with present in same sentence to show permanence of past?

Tags: tense, tense-agreement

Is this correct use of tense?

> "I observed that there *are* three baseline user cases..."

Or should the tense match? Such as this example,

> "I observed that there *were* three baseline user cases..."

To me it seems logical to use past tense that I observed and the present tense for the content of the observation since these observations are still valid and will be valid forever.

Comment: It depends on whether they are still (now) baseline user cases. Past tense only if not.

Comment: @user3169 they will always be the baseline user cases of this study but they will not necessarily be the baseline cases for other studies, though they could be. If there is any chance the tense change will confuse anyone (including non native speakers) then I'd just as soon use observed/were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *were* if you're referring to the past tense where the situation is no longer true. For a fuller sentence, you might have:

> I observed that there **were** three baseline user cases, *but now there are four*.

On the other hand, use *are* if it is still true.

> *Yesterday* I observed that there **are** three truths about life: we all die, life will find a way, and someone will always try to be the king.

The **observed** is in the past tense because the actions are in the past tense. Incidentally, it's good scientific practice to put the methods in the past tense (things that you've done to get where you are) and general conclusions in the present tense (since, presumably, what you found is still true for everyone).